# Build website with dashboard like Google Analytics with CMS or not?

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, dashboard, vs-web-site-project

I thought about building a website where people can answer questions and get a personal feedback in a backend (dashboard). For this I thought about software. First of all I thought about TYPO3? But I don't know if its a good choice.
Or do you recommend building it from scratch?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your usage of the term "backend" is not correct.
A 'backend', especially in a TYPO3 context, is the part of a website where only editors and administrators (backend users) have access and can change the website.

What you have in mind (as far as i understand) is a personalized page with results from the answered questions (form results).

As TYPO3 has the build in option to manage frontend users you could use it for individual logins and stored answers for presenting the results without requesting to answer the form each time.
A user needs to login, then answer the form and then you can generate the individual dashboard which also can be seen afterwards if the user logged in again.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpfull! Sorry for mixing up backend and dashboard

Comment: So can you recommend typo3 for such a website? Or do you know one which is specialized for that issue?